# How to get dataURL of Salesforce ContentVersion in LWC?

Tags: javascript, canvas, salesforce, lwc, todataurl

I am trying to get dataURL of Salesforce ContentVerison using canvas.toDataURL in LWC method but I am getting the following CORS policy error:
"[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDRyL.png)"

**LWC html code:**

```
<template>
    <div id="full-screen-image" class="full-screen-image">
        <img data-id="prev-image" src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Png&amp;versionId=06821000001Gsm8AAC&amp;operationContext=CHATTER&amp;contentId=05T21000004x5ga" class="testImage">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" class="slds-hide" data-id="prev-canvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
    </div>
</template>
```

**JS code**

```
handleRotateRight() {
    var image = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="prev-image"]');
    
    var canvas = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="prev-canvas"]');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.src = image.src;


    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        context.translate(canvas.width / 2,canvas.height / 2);
        context.rotate(Math.PI/2);
        
        context.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);

        //convert to png image as dataURL
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        console.log('dataURL-->', dataURL);
        //convert that as base64 encoding
        var convertedDataURI = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        console.log('convertedDataURI-->', convertedDataURI);

    }
}
```